# Auto-renewal Subscription in App purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I am working on a project for that I need auto-renewal subscription. I am done with back-end work but now my doubt is, "h**ow to get status of subscription. If user cancels or turns off the auto-renewal before renew the subscription**". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the receipt of the in-app purchase to check the expiration date. You can parse it yourself from the `NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL` or you can send it to apple and parse it from JSON response. See [Receipt Validation guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a small library to simplify to work with In-App Receipt locally. You can easily fetch the object that represents the receipt (`InAppReceipt`) and retrieve an active purchase/all purchases.

Feel free to use. [Github link](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt)

Here is an example of solving your problem:

```
import TPInAppReceipt

do {
    let receipt = try InAppReceiptManager.shared.receipt()

    //retrive active auto renewable subscription for a specific product and date
    let purchase = receipt.activeAutoRenewableSubscriptionPurchases(ofProductIdentifier: "ProductName", forDate: Date())

    //retrive all auto renewable subscription purchases for a specific product
    let allAutoRenewableSubscriptionPurchases = receipt.purchases(ofProductIdentifier: "productName").filter({ return $0.isRenewableSubscription })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```